# Why are the quark quantum numbers $S$ and $B$ defined to be $-1$ for $s,b$ ($+1$ for $\bar s,\bar b$)?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, conventions, quarks

For $s,c,b,t$ quarks we have quantum numbers $S,C,B,T$.
(For $u,d$ quarks we usually specify charge and baryon number, though we could also specify $U,D$.)

The quarks with charge $-1/3,~s$ and $b$, have negative quantum numbers $S=-1$ and $B=-1$, while those with charge $2/3,c$ and $t$, have positive quantum numbers $C=1$ and $T=1$.

Is this just an accident of history, or is there a reason for this? (If so, I suppose $d$ quarks should be defined to have $D=-1$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a convention that is easy to remember, so it was adopted:

- The flavor charge has the same sign as the electric charge.

With the advent of quarks, one simply writes down the quark content to avoid confusion and dyslexia...

For *d* and *u* quarks, people heed isospin, which yields more meaningful labels than pure *U* and *D* additive numbers; isospin composes more interestingly than simple addition of $I_3$.

One might argue, fancifully, that,  in this arrangement, you get the hypercharge in the [Gell-Mann—Nishijima formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann%E2%80%93Nishijima_formula) to replicate the isodoublet structure of the light quarks, for the upper two generations, where the up-like-down-like symmetry is badly broken, but the argument would be more confusing than clarifying, really...